# Creating an MD5 file for a directory tree for only a given extension

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, find, filter, md5

I would like to create an MD5 file of a directory tree, containing only the bare names of the files. [md5deep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5deep) exactly does that, but it cannot filter for files when in recursive mode.

```
md5deep -rb . > md5.txt
```

Is there any way to filter for (*.jpg) before outputting it to `md5.txt`? In Linux it would be just a `|`, but how do I do it in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

md5deep doesn't filter just those file you give in the filspec e.g. *.jpg. You can use find to generare the file list and pass it to `md5deep`

`find . -name '*.jpg' -exec md5deep -b {} + >>md5.txt`

You should delete the md5.txt file before running the code again otherwise it will have a new set of files appended to it.

Comment: This one looks professional. In the meantime, I've just done this 'md5deep -rb . | find /I ".jpg" > local.md5' Its not very efficient, because it hashes first, then filters the files, but in my case all the other files are really small files, so it doesn't make a change. But yours is definately better.